# Trying to add facebook to app with parse and app crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, crash, parse-platform

I am trying to add Facebook to my app and this is what i’ve done in the view controller :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.loginViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        [self.loginViewController setDelegate:self];
        [self.loginViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook];
        [self.loginViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me", nil]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

---

```
- (IBAction)faceBookLoginPressed:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:self.loginViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

And this causes the app to crash, and i get this :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a
>   nil modal view controller on target .'

In the app delegate I have :

```
 [Parse setApplicationId:@“********************************************"
               clientKey:@"********************************************"];
 [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
```

---

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

That is all I have for my first step. All I am trying to do is get my app to go to the web and have me log into Facebook like this does :

https://www.parse.com/tutorials/scrumptious

I am very confused so far with Parse, so please have patience with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you provide your applicationID and ClientKey to initialize Parse?

Comment: Yes, I did. I just covered them up

Comment: what is your crash log

Comment: Are you using XIB's or storyboards?

Comment: Storyboards, ill try your answer @i_duhh_bomb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What usually causes a ViewController to be nil is it not being initialized. Although I can see in your code that you have done that in here :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.loginViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        [self.loginViewController setDelegate:self];
        [self.loginViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook];
        [self.loginViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me", nil]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The problem is, this is only called if you have nibs i think. Correct me if i'm wrong. Because I can't see anything else wrong in your code. I am going to assume you are using storyboards. If this is the case replace this :

```
- (IBAction)faceBookLoginPressed:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:self.loginViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

with this

```
- (IBAction)faceBookLoginPressed:(id)sender {
    self.loginViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
    [self.loginViewController setDelegate:self];
    [self.loginViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook];
    [self.loginViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me", nil]];
    [self presentViewController:self.loginViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

And go ahead and delete this :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.loginViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
        [self.loginViewController setDelegate:self];
        [self.loginViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsFacebook];
        [self.loginViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me", nil]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Hope this was the case!